# Angular Display GMT Date time using pipe

Tags: angular

I know how to display the DateTime in angular using by pipe

```
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}
```

How to display the GMT time using a pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the above by making the following changes:

```
{{ today | date : 'medium':'GMT' }}
```

According to the [DatePipe documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe),

The 2nd parameter refers to the timezone. Therefore, you can simply just pass 'GMT' to your expression, and it should transform the date values to the required timezone.

> A timezone offset (such as '+0430'), or a standard UTC/GMT or
>   continental US timezone abbreviation. Default is the local system
>   timezone of the end-user's machine.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```