# Time changed automatically(Added +5:30 Hrs.) while displaying in HTML table. Needing the same received from Server

Tags: html, angular, date, datetime

I have a question. I got a response from server as below:

> CreatedDate: **"2020-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"**

When I display data in an HTML table (by this code)

```
<td> {{slot.CreatedDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"}} </td>
```

the date will be shown as the following:

> "25-06-2020 05:30"

But I need output like this:

> "25-06-2020 00:00"

which I have received from the server the same time. Please suggest to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374779/angular-display-gmt-date-time-using-pipe . See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your **dateformat**  as below.

```
{{ slot.CreatedDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'GMT+05:30':'en-US'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. but I need not 00:00 time. if I receive 12:30 time from the server, it will print 12:30 but it printed add "17:30".

Comment: You need to pass the timezone for this. You can use like this {{ slot.CreatedDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a' }}

Comment: i used above format also. but same 5:30 added automatically.

Comment: can u please connect to my anydesk once

Comment: use like this {{ slot.CreatedDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a':'en-US':'+0530'}}

Comment: Team Viewer:
1322874925
zn5d44

Comment: Please connect once

Comment: Checking... give 2mins plz

Comment: no bro. not working,same as before 5:30 added automatically while displaying

Comment: {{ slot.CreatedDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'+0530':'en-US'}}

Comment: create the stackblitz, than i can give the exact solution.

Comment: yeah i am using this 
{{ slot.CreatedDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'+0530':'en-US'}} 

same 5:30 added

Comment: Team Viewer: 
1322874925
zn5d44

Comment: Use this {{ slot.CreatedDate | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'GMT+05:30':'en-US'}}

Comment: yeah... will check and let u knows

Comment: Yeah, below code working but i have removed "+" from GMT05:30 then time displayed same as getting from server.

{{slot.CreatedDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'GMT05:30':'en-US'}}

thank you lot for ur help.

Comment: {{slot.SlotTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm':'GMT05:30'}}
working like above format also.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where I have to accept and upvote the answer.
Can u please suggest once. I will do it.